# Connecting two Windows 7 machines over ethernet

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I have a 30GB+ file I would like to transfer from one laptop to another so I am trying to do this by networking the machines together with an ethernet cable.

Both machines list the LAN connection then as unidentified and I can't modify them at all.  How can I work around this issue?

Comment: When you say you can't modify them at all, what does that mean? You ought to be able to manually put the computers on the same ip addresses range.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XUlc0.jpg This might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you:

- Used a Cross-over Ethernet cable to connect the two?
- Enabled both network adapters

Go to your network adapters properties and then the properties for the ipv4 setup

[image]

next you will need to set a manual ip address on both, i would suggest just using:

192.168.0.10 and 192.168.0.11 with a subnet of 255.255.255.0 for both and you should have a network set up that will connect the two.

[image]

Comment: I am not using a crossover cable.  I didn't know that there was no way to do it with a standard cable.  Guess I need to go to the store then.

Comment: If you have a switch then you can use two standard straight through cables, but if you want to directly connect two systems together without a switch or hub then you'll need a cross-over.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I think a crossover cable is not needed if both NICs are gigabit - it's part of the standard to deal with a straight-through cable.